# dsRESTConnection component won't allow me change the .username and .password after the first connect

Tags: rest, delphi, datasnap

In my Delphi 10.3.1 application server (which is a "DataSnap REST Application"), I have put some logging as follows:

```
procedure TWebModule1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
  Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
  var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);
begin
  valid := (User > '') and (Password > ''); // pass-through
  if Valid then
  begin
    MyWebUtils.LogMessage('Authentication, ' + User + ', ' + Password +
      ', ' + protocol + ', ' + context);
    TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession.PutData('USERNAME', User);
  end;
end;
```

In my client (on Android), which uses a dsRestConnection, I have a procedure to test the connection, which I call, for example in FormShow of the main form.

```
function TClientModuleRest.TestConnect(var ErrorMsg: String): Boolean;
var
  returned: String;
begin
  Result := True;
    try
      DSRestConnection.Username := 'Admin';
      DSRestConnection.Password := 'Test';
      DSRestConnection.TestConnection([toNoLoginPrompt]);
    except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      Result := False;
      ErrorMsg := e.Message;
    end
    end;
end;
```

This works well.

The problem occurs when I call the first Server method.

```
function TClientModuleRest.ValidUser(username, password: String;
  var Response: String): Integer;
var
  Server: TServerMethodsRClient;
  Valid: Boolean;
  IniFile: TStringList;
  FileName: TFileName;
begin

  Result := 0;

  DSRestConnection.UserName := username;
  DSRestConnection.Password := password;

  try
    Server := TServerMethodsRClient.Create(DSRestConnection);
    try
      Valid := Server.ValidUser(username, password, Response);
      if not Valid then
        raise Exception.Create(response);
      Result := 1;
    finally
      Server.Free;
    end;
  except
  on e: exception do
  begin
    Response := e.Message;
    Result := -1; // an error occured
  end;
  end;
end;
```

So the problem is that the setting of the `.username` and `.password` doesn't 'take'. In other words, my conclusion is that the `.username` and `.password can only be set *before the first connect*, and not thereafter.

The server log file shows that even though the ValidUser function was called with the username and password values that were passed to it, the authentication is receiving the username and password from the first (test) connect.

Is this by design? Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger with DSRestConnection? If it is by design, the property setter will prevent changing its value it after a connection is established.

Comment: @mjn42 That seems to be the case. Of course, a connection does not persist for any longer than necessary, so the correct statement is "the property setter will prevent change it's value after the first connection has come and gone"